# How to properly return an image from QLThumbnailGenerator? (SwiftUI)

Tags: swiftui, quicklook

**My Problem**
How do I return a cgImage from QLThumbnailGenerator.shared.generateRepresentations(for: ... )?

**My Hangups/Attempt (Code Below)**
My attempt has a function (line 13) that returns a CGImage for a ListView entry (line 39). I tried to use an empty CGImage (line 18), but its init parameters are confusing and seem excessive for a simple thumbnail. I'm likely going about this incorrectly.

**Notes**
CGImage is used so the same code can work for both iOS and MacOS Catalyst. (Saw this in WWDC 2019 session 719.)
I tried but failed to glean an answer from:
 - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quicklookthumbnailing/creating_quick_look_thumbnails_to_preview_files_in_your_app
 - https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/375807

**Apology/Gratitude**
Thanks for your patience, as the answer is likely obvious and my vocabulary likely off. My dumb brain tunes out lectures without a little hands-on experience, so I started this first app from zero programming knowledge as a quarantine hobby. I'll return to the theory lectures after.

**ResultsView.swift**

```
import SwiftUI
import MobileCoreServices
import Combine
import QuickLookThumbnailing
import CoreImage
import UIKit

struct ResultsView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var parsedScreeningData: ParsedScreeningData
    @EnvironmentObject var search: Search

    func generateThumbnail(ofThis: String) -> CGImage {
        let url = self.search.libraryFolder.appendingPathComponent(ofThis)
        let size: CGSize = CGSize(width: 68, height: 88)
        let request = QLThumbnailGenerator.Request(fileAt: url, size: size, scale: (UIScreen.main.scale), representationTypes: .all)
        let generator = QLThumbnailGenerator.shared

        var image = CGImage()

        generator.generateRepresentations(for: request) { (thumbnail, type, error) in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if thumbnail == nil || error != nil {
                    assert(false, "Thumbnail failed to generate")
                } else {
                    image = thumbnail!.cgImage
                }
            }
        }
        return image
    }



var body: some View {
    VStack{

        List(search.searchResults) { datum in
            HStack {
                Image(self.generateThumbnail(ofThis: datum.PDFname), scale: (UIScreen.main.scale), label: Text("PDF"))
                Text("File: \(datum.PDFname)")
                Text("Cell line: \(self.parsedScreeningData.parsedScreeningData[datum.termFoundIndex].misidentifiedCellLine)")
                    .padding(.trailing, 10)
                    .padding(.leading, 10)
                Spacer()
                Image(systemName: "eyeglasses").foregroundColor(ColorManager.iconGreen)
                } // HStack
            } // List
        }// Vstack
        .colorMultiply(ColorManager.beigeMedium)
            .padding(.trailing, 0)
            .padding(.leading, 0)
            .listStyle(GroupedListStyle())

    } // body
} // ResultsView struct


struct ResultsView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ResultsView().environmentObject(ParsedScreeningData()).environmentObject(Search())
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Thumbnails generation is asynchronous so it needs some wrapper view which wait util thumbnail generated showing some stub placeholder and update when thumbnail is ready.

Here is possible solution

1. usage of thumbnail holder view

```
List(search.searchResults) { datum in
    HStack {
        ThumbnailImageView(url: self.search.libraryFolder.appendingPathComponent(datum.PDFname))
        Text("File: \(datum.PDFname)")

        // ... other your code here
```

2. thumbnail view itself

```
struct ThumbnailImageView: View {
    let url: URL

    @State private var thumbnail: CGImage? = nil

    var body: some View {
        Group {
            if thumbnail != nil {
                Image(self.thumbnail!, scale: (UIScreen.main.scale), label: Text("PDF"))
            } else {
                Image(systemName: "photo") // << any placeholder
                  .onAppear(perform: generateThumbnail) // << here !! 
            }
        }
    }

    func generateThumbnail() {
        let size: CGSize = CGSize(width: 68, height: 88)
        let request = QLThumbnailGenerator.Request(fileAt: url, size: size, scale: (UIScreen.main.scale), representationTypes: .all)
        let generator = QLThumbnailGenerator.shared

        generator.generateRepresentations(for: request) { (thumbnail, type, error) in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if thumbnail == nil || error != nil {
                    assert(false, "Thumbnail failed to generate")
                } else {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async { // << required !!
                        self.thumbnail = thumbnail!.cgImage  // here !!
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is `generateThumbnail(ofThis:)` called?

Comment: @ChuckKrutsinger, in can be called in `.onAppear` of placeholder - see updated.